# How do I normalize my table?

Tags: database, normalization

I have a table that consists of 1440 columns in a MySQL database. The columns names are:
`id`,`name`,`email`,`phonenumber`,and also `datewithtime` columns like 1'st january_2012_00:00, 1'st january_2012_00:30, 1'st january_2012_01:00, 1'st january_2012_01:00, 1'st january_2012_02:00,..., 1'st january_2012_24:00.

Can I maintain all of these columns in a single table or can I divide the single table into multiple tables and make an association between them?  What is the best solution for me?

Comment: What are the datewithtime columns being used for?

Answer (score 1):

You should create a table containing (UserId, SomeDateColumnName, SomeValueColumnName)

Then, the value of each column in your table will go into a row in this new table. Ex:

instead of

```
Id  Name  Email  Phone  1stjanuary_2012_00:00  1stjanuary_2012_00:30 ...
1   A     A@A.A  123    Value 1                Value 2
```

You will have

```
Id  Name  Email  Phone
1   A     A@A.A  123
```

plus

```
UserId  DateColumn           ValueColumn
1       2012-01-01 00:00:00  Value 1
1       2012-01-01 00:30:00  Value 2
1       2012-01-01 01:00:00  Value 3
1       2012-01-01 01:30:00  Value 4
...
2       2012-01-01 00:00:00  Value 123
2       2012-01-01 00:30:00  Value 234
2       2012-01-01 01:00:00  Value 345
2       2012-01-01 01:30:00  Value 456
...
```

Comment: first of all thanks cuberdude.sorry for the late reply.i normalize my table on that way.its working properly...